# Call Javascript function from external file with Applescript

Tags: javascript, function, applescript, photoshop-script

Is it possible to call a javascript file function in applescript? I can get it to work when written 100% in the applescript file or I can use "do javascript file some file". Is there a way to mix the two? Something like this:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
    tell current document
        do javascript "function(Variable1,Variable1)" in file PathtoJSX
    end tell
end tell
```

The function is located in the external file but I want to pass it variables from applescript.

**Update:**

I posted it when someone else ask but PathtoJSX is the "Path to Javascript file (.jsx)" so PathtoJSX = file "desktop:yourFile.jsx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is have the function part of the code in the file and send the arguments via AppleScript as a list (Array), which is pretty easy to do:

The contents of the jsx file could be:

```
testFunc(arguments);

function testFunc(t) {
 alert('argument one: ' + t[0] + '\r' + 'argument two: ' + t[1]);
}
```

and the AppleScript could be:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
  activate
  do javascript PathtoJSX with arguments {"foo", "bar"}
      --I tested using:-- do javascript (choose file) with arguments {"foo", "bar")
end tell
```

Whatever you use for the JS code (text or file), you just make sure you use the **arguments** array reference in that code. *Note that if you test this (as I did) by using a text variable instead of an alias (file reference), the return character would need a double escape.*

Comment: The key for me was the 'arguments' variable name to be passed in, being required. I was trying to do my own 'args' argument but it didn't work - so this answer helped with that.

Answer (score 1):

Has this changed since it was first solved? The following worked for me:

*JavaScript*

```
function testFunc(t) {
 alert('argument one: ' + t[0] + '\r' + 'argument two: ' + t[1]);
}

testFunc(arguments);
```

*AppleScript*

```
tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
    activate
    do javascript of file "pathToFile" with arguments {"foo", "bar"}
end tell
```

---

*See also:*

[Applescript + Javascript and scriptListener](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/request-add-scale-styles-option-to-quot-resize-image-quot-command-in-applescript/m-p/10637321)

[AppleScript wants you to escape double quotes in inline JavaScript](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/running-a-jsx-script-with-applescript-in-photoshop-using-do-javascript/td-p/11035403)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS4"
 activate
 do javascript (file "/Users/Michael/Desktop/somescript.jsx") with arguments {"foo", "bar"}
end tell
```

Regards.

Comment: This is a redundant post. The question was already answered with the same information. Please read all answer before posting.

Comment: This is useful because it shows a different syntax of calling a JS file.